# Ошибки работы VisualStudio с репозиторием

Tags: c#, visual-studio, репозиторий, devops

Помогите разобраться с проблемой.
После синхронизации репозитория с azure devops, у меня с двумя формами в проекте возникает проблема. Студия думает что данные формы были отредактированы локально, при этом изменение из репозитория не применяются, если синхронизировать такие формы то потеряешь последние изменения. Обратил внимание что проблема возникает если формы были отредактированы ранее на другом компьютере. Операции: "Сравнить форму с не измененной" просто показывает старую форму без изменений, "Отменить изменения" ни к чему не приводят.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема была как в предыдущей, так и в 2019 студии.

Comment: А вы для начала чётко определитесь: есть изменения или нету? Я например знаю, что csproj может поменять дату модификации (и для гит это сигнал, что файл изменился), при этом сравнение контента показывает что ничего не поменялось. Второй момент. Показ изменений может идти в двух режимах (настройка Ignore Trim whitespaces) и может быть так, что изменения контента ЕСТЬ, но НЕ ВИДНЫ.

Comment: Изменений точно нет. Я вчера на рабочем месте синхронизировался их не трогал. Дома поработал, внес правки в эти документы.  Пришел на работу, после синхронизации эти формы стали измененными, но изменений которые я сделал дома не видны. Когда я нажимаю отменить изменения, у файлов .cs этих форм меняться время изменения.